# Nasty integration?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

So I am trying to solve the following integral and apparently its not integrable or I might be wrong. Not even computer software can integrate.

Can anyone tell me if this is integrable or not? The function is the following,

$$\int_{y}^{+\infty} \left(\frac{ \left(1-\exp \left(- x^{0.25}\right)\right)}{x^{0.5}}+\exp \left(- \sqrt{x}\right)\right)
\left(\exp \left(-s \ x^{-1}\right)-1\right) \mathrm dx$$

where $s$ is just a constant and $y$ is a positive constant.

Comment: Are you sure you are after the indefinite integral, and not a definite integral with some limits?

Comment: Added the limits @MarkFischler thanks

Comment: As a point of technicality, the expression above is called an "integral" not an "integration". The process of solving the integral is integration

Comment: The integrand is equivalent to $-s/x^{3/2}$ when $x\to\infty$ hence OF COURSE this function is integrable on every $(y,+\infty)$, $y\gt0$.

Comment: Just a general remark: there's no chance of integrating this analytically unless you get rid of the roots in the exponents. So $u=x^{1/4}$ is pretty much the only option you have. However, integrals with such variety are usually hopeless.

Comment: However, just proving integrability is easy, just check the limiting behaviour, where most of the terms can be simplified.

Comment: @orion $\exp x^{1/n}$ is always integrable using elementary functions, so it's not the roots in exponents alone that make it impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$\int_y^\infty\left(\dfrac{1-e^{-\sqrt[4]x}}{\sqrt{x}}+e^{-\sqrt{x}}\right)(e^{-\frac{s}{x}}-1)~dx$

$=\lim\limits_{z\to\infty}\int_y^z\left(\dfrac{1-e^{-\sqrt[4]x}}{\sqrt{x}}+e^{-\sqrt{x}}\right)(e^{-\frac{s}{x}}-1)~dx$

$=\lim\limits_{z\to\infty}\left(\int_y^z\dfrac{(1-e^{-\sqrt[4]x})(e^{-\frac{s}{x}}-1)}{\sqrt{x}}dx+\int_y^ze^{-\sqrt{x}}(e^{-\frac{s}{x}}-1)~dx\right)$

$=\lim\limits_{z\to\infty}\left(\int_y^z2(1-e^{-\sqrt[4]x})(e^{-\frac{s}{x}}-1)~d(\sqrt{x})+\int_y^ze^{-\sqrt{x}}(e^{-\frac{s}{x}}-1)~dx\right)$

$=\lim\limits_{z\to\infty}\left(\int_\sqrt{y}^\sqrt{z}2(1-e^{-\sqrt{x}})(e^{-\frac{s}{x^2}}-1)~dx+\int_y^ze^{-\sqrt{x}}(e^{-\frac{s}{x}}-1)~dx\right)$

Comment: The problem is you have expanded the factor on the right. You can expand the other one safely, though.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut: I have modified my answer, but how can I eliminate the divergent parts?

Comment: What is divergent? I'm not sure one can compute the integrals in "closed form", but they look convergent to me.